# how to block referrer spam using htccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, spam, referrer

My website is getting to much referrer spam so i added following code in my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} floating-share-buttons.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 4webmasters.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} trafficmonetizer.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} erot.co [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} yourserverisdown.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} event-tracking.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} traffic2money.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} buttons-for-website.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} success-seo.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} free-social-buttons.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} Get-Free-Traffic-Now.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} e-buyeasy.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} videos-for-your-business.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} callgirlservices.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ – [F,L]
```

from http://99webtools.com/blog/block-referrer-spam-with-htaccess/
but i am still getting referrer from above websites.
Help me in blocking these spam

Comment: Can using `^[\S\s]+$` help ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the .htaccess method only stops so-called "crawler" referral spam, where each page is manually crawled. So-called "ghost" referral may only spoof a visit to your site using your analytics cookie settings retrieved by an earlier visit (or from another domain).

I've found that the only way to successfully remove these "visits" from my Analytics statistics is filters. Either explicitly by naming bad referrers or by using valid holst name filters.

To filter out bad referrers, go to you analytics tool (for me Google Analytics), Admin, All filters, and add a new filter to exclude by host name.

Both methods outlined in this (an other) articles:
http://linchpinseo.com/how-to-block-referral-spam-google-analytics-filters-htaccess